# GCC linking multiple memory banks

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, elf

1. `rom1` and `rom2` have different address map and are not continuous!
2. some objects have to be placed into `rom2`.
3. every time `rom1` is linked, objects in `rom2` should be the fixed address(`rom2`). In other words, `rom1` should know `rom2`'s symbols' address when linking.

Can I link an elf(`rom2`) into `rom1`?

Comment: can i link a elf(rom2) into rom1?

Comment: or can i split rom2 related functions from rom1 elf, assuming rom2 related functions is in special sction?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well :

1. your system has 2 memories `rom1` and `rom2`
2. some objects have to be located in `rom1`, others in `rom2`

Your link script shall look like the following :

```
 MEMORY
 {
     rom1 : org=0x10000 len=1024
     rom2 : org=0x40000 len=1024
 }

 SECTIONS 
 {
     .text1  0x10000 : {foo.o(.text) } > rom1
     .text2  0x40000 : {bar.o(.text) } > rom2
 }
```

In the part `SECTIONS` the linker collects the `.text` sections from `foo.o` and puts this .text section within the output section .text1 starting at address 0x10000 in rom1.

Similarly, it collects the `.text` section from `bar.o`  and puts it in rom2.